# How to add a Traefik service to an existing Docker Swarm cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a web application that I can deploy successfully using Docker Swarm with a Compose file:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml common
```

and is described by the file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  www:
    image: localhost:5000/www.learnintouch
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "444:443"
    networks:
      common:
networks:
  common:
    name: common
```

Now I add a Traefik service to it:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - target: 81
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        mode: host
      - target: 444
        published: 443
        mode: host
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=common
        - traefik.constraint-label=common
        - traefik.docker.lbswarm=true
    command:
      --log.level=DEBUG
      --api.insecure=true
      --providers.docker
      --providers.docker.swarmmode
      --accesslog
      --api.dashboard=true
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/traefik/logs:/traefiklog"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/traefik/rules:/rules"
  www:
    image: localhost:5000/www.learnintouch
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "444:443"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.www_learnintouch.rule=Host('www_learnintouch.docker.localhost')"
    networks:
      common:
networks:
  common:
    name: common
  default:
    driver: overlay
```

The containers are deployed:

```
22:49 $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                                                                                                                         NAMES
ff38498c061f   localhost:5000/www.learnintouch:latest      "/bin/bash /usr/loca…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)                                                                                                                                 www_learnintouch_www.1.n9mvfo64hp8unzvcau6rws99q
df070019539f   traefik:latest                              "/entrypoint.sh --lo…"   2 minutes ago        Up 2 minutes                  80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->81/tcp, :::80->81/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->444/tcp, :::443->444/tcp   common_traefik.1.t141a053tvcbi0ql5ztbjmfgp
```

But there are some issues with the port mappings:

```
common_traefik.1.t141a053tvcb@stephane-pc    | time="2021-06-13T20:52:24Z" level=error msg="service \"common-traefik\" error: port is missing" providerName=docker container=common-traefik-m6sxqj8giwuex2jlbrsgilsm9
common_traefik.1.t141a053tvcb@stephane-pc    | time="2021-06-13T20:52:39Z" level=error msg="service \"www-learnintouch-www\" error: port is missing" providerName=docker container=www-learnintouch-www-n9mvfo64hp8unzvcau6rws99q
common_traefik.1.t141a053tvcb@stephane-pc    | time="2021-06-13T20:53:24Z" level=warning msg="Could not find network named 'common' for container 'common_traefik'! Maybe you're missing the project's prefix in the label? Defaulting to first available network." providerName=docker container=common-traefik-m6sxqj8giwuex2jlbrsgilsm9 serviceName=common-traefik
```

I did not create a network manually with another command, since I never needed to do it before adding the `Traefik` service.

As a `Traefik` and network dummy I was hoping for an easy installation without having to manually specify hostnames redundantly, and without having to run some external commands as well.

After a search for hints I found this [opened issue](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/5732) but I could not figure out what to make of it.

UPDATE: I added a port to all the services as in:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.http.routers.www_learnintouch.rule=Host('www_learnintouch.docker.localhost')"
  - "traefik.http.services.www.loadbalancer.server.port=5000"
```

but the log still shows the same error message.

UPDATE: The file after the provided solution:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    networks:
      common:
    ports:
      - target: 81
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 444
        published: 443
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        - "traefik.constraint-label=common"
    command:
      --log.level=DEBUG
      --api.insecure=true
      --providers.docker
      --providers.docker.swarmmode
      --accesslog
      --api.dashboard=true
      --providers.docker.network=common
      --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      --providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{normalize .Name}}.docker.local`)
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/traefik/logs:/traefiklog"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/traefik/rules:/rules"
  logrotate:
    image: localhost:5000/logrotate
    networks:
      common:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/logrotate/logs"
    user: "${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_GID}"
    environment:
      HOST_USER_ID: ${CURRENT_UID}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${CURRENT_GID}
  www:
    image: localhost:5000/www.learnintouch
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.www.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    networks:
      common:
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.learnintouch/account/data:/usr/local/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/account/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/www.learnintouch/account/backup:/usr/local/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/account/backup"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/engine:/usr/local/learnintouch/engine"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/letsencrypt/certbot/conf/live/thalasoft.com:/usr/local/learnintouch/letsencrypt"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/apache/logs"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/common/volumes/logs:/usr/local/learnintouch/logs"
    user: "${CURRENT_UID}:${CURRENT_GID}"
    environment:
      HOST_USER_ID: ${CURRENT_UID}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${CURRENT_GID}
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_PORT: 3306
      WWW_LEARNINTOUCH_DB_NAME: db_learnintouch
      WWW_LEARNINTOUCH_DB_USER: learnintouch
      WWW_LEARNINTOUCH_NAME: learnintouch
      WWW_LEARNINTOUCH_DOMAIN: dev.learnintouch.com
      WWW_LEARNINTOUCH_SCHEME: http
      STAFF_EMAIL: mittiprovence@yahoo.se
      NODEJS_SOCKET_PORT: 9001
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:80/engine/ping.php || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
networks:
  common:
    name: common
  default:
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In docker swarm mode traefik cant (for some reason!?) detect the ports that services are listening on.

As such, every docker service needs to have a label of the form:

`"traefik.http.services.www_learnintouch.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"`

--

I missed in the first pass that there is a `www` service.

You need to remove the `ports` section from `www` as traefik needs to handle ingress, and be the service that actually exposes those ports.

Then, you also need to add `networks: [ common ]` to traefik, as it can't do this routing without sharing a common network.

Finally, traefik exposes all services by default, and so will emit errors for any and all services on your swarm that are not configured with a full/minimal set of traefik labels including itself. For some reason the maintainers are deaf to the idea that this is stupid and should be fixed.

If we fix these issues, I would suggest a traefik service that looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host
    networks:
      - common
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    command:
      --log.level=DEBUG
      --api.insecure=true
      --providers.docker
      --providers.docker.swarmmode
      --accesslog
      --api.dashboard=true
      --providers.docker.network=common
      --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      --providers.docker.defaultRule=Host(`{{normalize .Name}}.docker.local`)
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

And your `www` service would be:

```yaml
 www_learnintouch:
    image: localhost:5000/www.learnintouch
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.www_learnintouch.loadbalancer.server.port=80
    networks:
      common:
```

Comment: I added a port number like you suggested but the error remained the same. I also edited the question so as to give more context. Do I miss another label ?

Comment: What about the other error message `Could not find network named 'common' for container 'common_traefik'` ?

Comment: After updating the configuration I still get the errors `common-traefik error: port is missing` and `common-www error: port is missing` and `Could not find network named 'common' for container 'common_traefik`. Also how to avoid this port error for a service like logrotate that has no server ?

Comment: With `--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false`, evey service needs `traefik.enable=true` to be considered by traefik. i.e. dont enable traefik for logrotate.
Other than that the errors make no sense unless you are looking at old logs. Tried a `docker stack rm common` before reapplying?

Comment: I wish it was such a simple mistake of mine :-) But I do run the log viewing command `docker service logs -f common_traefik` each time after doing a `docker stack rm common` and a `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml common`. I had guessed the expose by default to false was requiring any service that wants to be seen to have its own `traefik.enable=true` and at first I didn't have it for the `logrotate` but it didn't help so I tried `traefik.enable=false` and it didn't help either. Maybe I do need to manually create a network before running the compose file ?

Comment: well, my compose file fragments where not meant to be complete and covered just the service, not the network definitions. The network definition, as you had it for "common" was fine and should have been retained.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised when you say `should have been retained`. You saw some change on my common network ? Now, after looking at my network I see I have a default one and that is a mistake, I don't know why I put it there, so instead I now tried having `networks:
  common:
    name: common
    driver: overlay` and after stopping and starting the stack the `common_traefik` log remains empty. But I still cannot access the website on port 80. It says `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: You are trying to access the site using the "traefik.docker.local" and "www_learnintouch.docker.local" addresses? I am presuming you have done some kind of extra setup to get wildcard name resolution on this domain returning 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Before adding the Traefik service I could access my website at `http://dev.learnintouch.com` Is it still possible ? I have this entry specified in my `/etc/hosts` file: `127.0.1.1 dev.learnintouch.com`

Comment: And my www service is serving two websites each with its own domain name specified in the Apache `vhost.conf` file.

Comment: For a traefik to route requests to a service, just add multiple entries to the Host rule for that service - i.e. add this to your www service labels: ` - traefik.http.routers.www_learnintouch.rule=Host("dev.learnintouch.com","www.docker.local")` or whatever other mappings you have to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I still get the same `This site can’t be reached` error in the browser. Here is the mapping I now have: `labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.www.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.www.rule=Host('dev.learnintouch.com')"` The `traefik` service and `www` service logs show no error.

Comment: 's are not valid string markers for traefik Host rules : As they are parsed as go-strings you can use "s or `s, 's are used for single characters.

Comment: The error remained identical after the change of single quotes to back quotes or double quotes. I shall accept your answer anyway for all the good points you provided me with. The log shows no error still. I shall ask another question since I now have a correct Traefik configuration file.